# Symbian emulator to run Ngage games

Tags: emulation

I don't really know if this is the correct place to ask this, if not let me know where I should. I would like to know if it would be possible to run Ngage games on an existing Symbian emulator.

There is no emulator for Ngage games, however, some games had support for Nokia N97 and probably other Nokia phones.

If the answer is affirmative, what software would I need?

Comment: Welcome to the Recocomputing StackExchange. The Ngage is somewhat obscure, but it should qualify as a "retro" gaming console and there are many questions here related to those.

Comment: Back in its day, hacked versions of NGage titles that would work on more normal handsets such as the 6600 used to make the illegal rounds. I have no idea whether Series 60 2nd Edition was a requirement, but if not then since that's the same hardware as the original 7650 one imagines an emulator for any of the Series 60 handsets should have 95% of what's required. I'm inclined to guess the N-Gage didn't offer any additional hardware, such as a GPU.

Comment: @Tommy Your guess is correct. The N-Gage didn't really have any game hardware other than the easy to use game card slot (yes, sarcasm) and the D-pad. They were basically just a fast processor and a frame buffer. I worked on a few N-Gage titles, and if you thought changing games was a pain, consider that the only way to debug games on the first gen was to write log files to the card :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for an N-Gage emulator, this seems to be the most active project at the moment.

https://github.com/EKA2L1/EKA2L1

As far as I'm aware, you do in fact need an emulator for the N-Gage itself to run games.

**Edit:** The EKA2L1 project has finally developed an experimental Symbian OS emulator. The emulator currently emulates Symbian OS's EKA1 and EKA2 behavior, and reimplement most of its critical app servers. It can already boot many EKA2's apps and games, with EKA1 being worked on at the moment.

Comment: EKA2L1 has finally released an emulator that can run Ngage games!